# Sharp borders using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying for tag `SOLD OUT` as shown in below `figure`

[image]

but able to achieve upto certain extend shown in below figure

[image]

using following HTML & CSS

```
<a href="some-href">
  <img src="img-url">
  <div class="wp-sold-out-strip">SOLD OUT</div>
</a>

.wp-sold-out-strip {
text-align: center;
background-color: #8760AF;
width: 142px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0px 0px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -47px;
transform: rotate(-26deg);    
}
```

Comment: set more width....

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: tried its not working

Comment: Share what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

- set the parent's `position` to `relative`(the  in your case) and `overflow` to `hidden`.
- set the "sold out"'s `width` to something that will overflow and the image's `height` and `width` to `100%` to fill the parent

You'll need the `position:relative` of the parent so the "sold out" will be aligned to its parent when `position:absolute` and the `overflow:hidden`  will be applied to it.

```
.parent {overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block; width: 200px; height: 200px;}
.parent img { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.wp-sold-out-strip {
text-align: center;
background-color: #8760AF;
width: 242px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0px 0px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -47px;
transform: rotate(-26deg);    
}

<a href="some-href" class="parent">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmww2.png">
  <div class="wp-sold-out-strip">SOLD OUT</div>
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/snxt61an/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, set `backface-visibility:hidden`

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
a > img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
a > .wp-sold-out-strip {
width: 180px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
background-color: #8760AF;
bottom:20px;
right:-30px;
transform:rotate(-30deg);
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="some-href">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu">
  <div class="wp-sold-out-strip">SOLD OUT</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution!...

Try this code...

```
<div class="img-wraper">
  <a href="some-href" class="">
    <img src="img-url">
    <div class="wp-sold-out-strip">SOLD OUT</div>
  </a>
</div>


<style media="screen">
  .img-wraper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 4px solid #cccccc;
  }
  .img-wraper a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .img-wraper a img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .wp-sold-out-strip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: -30px;
    width: 142px;
    transform: rotate(-33deg);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #8760AF;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer for you.  [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yeg674v1/)

What I did to set the parent element a `position: relative` and `position: absolute` on the banner. You can then more easily align the item with `top` and `left`.

It's also important to set the parent to `overflow: hidden` so that nothing appears to protrude outside your image. Finally, you need to override the default `inline` behavior of anchor tags so that you can align the banner properly.

I also increased the left padding for the text to make it appear centered.

```css
.wp-sold-out-strip {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #8760AF;
  width: 170px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 107px;
  left: -2px;
  transform: rotate(-26deg);
}
a {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="some-href">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150">
  <div class="wp-sold-out-strip">SOLD OUT</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
height:30px;
line-height:28px;
```

and change this value:

```
margin-top: -70px;
```

Demo (new tag in orange, old in purple), enjoy:

```css
.wp-sold-out-strip {
text-align: center;
background-color: tomato;
width: 142px;
height:30px;
line-height:28px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0px 0px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -70px;
transform: rotate(-26deg);    
}
```

```html
<a href="some-href">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nahj0.png">
  <div class="wp-sold-out-strip">SOLD OUT</div>
</a>
```